# If an R package's licence X is, do all the content in that package have to be licenced under X?

Tags: r, licensing, package

Hope the question above is clear.

Now my case: For my package, i'm using several libraries (jars). Each library has been licenced under one of these:  Apache v2, BSD or LPGL.

**Edit** [some clarification] I have my own java classes packed in a jar. These import classes (dynamic linking) from the libraries mentioned here [End Edit]

Question 1: Can i pack all these libraries in a single package?
Question 1a: If yes, under what licence Apache, BSD, LGPL or any other?
Question 1b: If yes, would it be enough to put all the library names in a NOTICE and to write under what licence is a library licenced together?

Question 2: Or do i have to create for each type of licence a separate package and put libraries in it according to their licence type?

Comment: The question is clear, then you muddy things by talking about libraries and jars. Sounds like java talk to me. Have you got java code in your R package? Or did you just cut n paste this from a question about packaging java libraries?

Comment: Yes, it is Java. My own java classes are packed in a separate jar, which will be an open source and i call the java classes from an R function. I did not understand your last question. What do you mean with cut n paste? Thanks.

Comment: If the java code is yours and the R code in the package is yours, why not re-licence the java jars under whathever licence you want to release the R package? It would make things a lot simpler, and if you do own the java code then it is easy for you to release it under  a different licence as part of the R package.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 6):

You can't use a single license for your package.  Instead, in your `DESCRIPTION` put "License: file LICENSE" and describe the individual licenses in that file.

Comment: So i create this new LICENSE file and write in it something like this: All contents created by me is from this license and then i list all library and mention from what licenses they are. Is there a template for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

R itself is licensed under the GPL. It contains other functionality released under different licences, such a PCRE which is licensed under BSD. The R sources contain separate licence files for the different components as well as copyright statements/acknowledgements.

**Edit** [some clarification] So in and of itself, if you are redistributing libraries as part of your package you need to preserve their licence details and respect the licence under which they were distributed. Your package can have whatever licence you want as long as it is not in conflict with the licences of the libraries you are redistributing (unlikely given the ones you cite). You make clear what licence your package is under in the `DESCRIPTION` file (as Hadley mentions in his answer), but you should make sure a `LICENCE`, or `COPYING` file is included in the top level of the package source so it is clear what code is under what licence etc.
[End edit]

The problem you are going to have is that unless we have some lawyers hereabouts who are coders, any advice given should be taken with a big pinch of salt. If you are worried about this, you should seek expert advice.

Comment: Ditto TZHX's comment on the -1 here too?

Comment: In the DESCRIPTION i write whatever my package's license is and in a file in the top level directory of my package i mention all other libraries with their license names. Did i understand correct?

Comment: @ilhami: Yes, I think. The DESCRIPTION requires the package licence to be in a specific format. See this for details: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file . It is worth having something in the top-level of your package source that points to the licence or licences under which the software in the package is being used. Note, however that this file will not be *installed* in binary packages. For that you need to have the file in a `inst/` directory. It really is up to you how you arrange this.

Answer (score 2):

You are focused on packaging. While a collection of packages can be considered a compilation and not a derivative work, allowing redistribution under relaxed conditions, the software that depends on them is likely a derivative work, and copyright places stronger restrictions on its redistribution.

If you are talking Apache 2 and LGPL 2+ or 3+ for the libraries: all of these licences are GPLv3-compatible. The GPL3+ could be a common denominator that allows you to redistribute a derivative work based on those libraries (your solution 1a).

However, if all you do is linking, the LGPL and the Apache licence have an exemption that lets you redistribute your software as if it wasn't a derivative, and the BSD lets you licence the derivative with very few conditions.

This allows you to go with option 1b. You should have a NOTICE file that describes under which package the files you distribute are, and what licence each of them is under. Ship the licences as well, in individual files for the longer ones.

Comment: To clarify: In this package i have my own java classes in a jar that uses other libraries. My classes are called from an R function. From your saying, it makes my jar and the R functions a derivative work, right? And i can choose LGPL or Apache for my own jar, scripts etc... What can i write in the DESCRIPTION in your opinion? Thanks..

Comment: @ilhami The jar and R code are derivative, but you can pick almost any licence for them anyway thanks to these dynamic linking exemptions. I just felt like giving the complete reasoning behind this. Have DESCRIPTION's License field refer to NOTICE, like hadley suggests; I picked NOTICE because that's what Apache 2 calls it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the LGPL files aren't just LGPL-2 [which is not GPL-3 compatible] but LGPL-2 (or any higher version), LGPL-2.1, or LGPL-3 then all those licenses should be GPL-3 compatible and you could release your R package with an overall GPL-3 license.

I have packages (optparse, argparse) on CRAN under an overall GPL (>=2) license that combines GPL (>=2) code with code under the GPL-compatible Python license which contains a mandatory license notice.

Here is a good resource that the FSF directed me to about incorporating gpl-compatible code with mandatory copyright notices with GPL code: http://www.softwarefreedom.org/resources/2007/gpl-non-gpl-collaboration.html

In terms of making CRAN happy it turns out if the overall package is GPL'ed that they do not like in the DESCRIPTION that the license field says LICENSE or (GPL >= 2) + LICENSE where LICENSE contains all the permissive copyright notices you need to preserve. In particular they forced me to remove such a LICENSE file. However they seemed okay that in DESCRIPTION under Author you give a high-level description of where you got all the software from, under License say GPL-3 and then under Copyright say "See file (inst/)COPYRIGHTS. In (inst/)COPYRIGHTS you can include all the copyright notices you are required to preserve. I use the Debian Package Copyright Format http://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/ but you don't need to. You can also look at the COPYRIGHT file in the R source for formatting ideas.  "Writing R Extensions" specifically mentions inst/COPYRIGHTS as a place package authors can place additional information so it might preferable for the file to be called that rather than NOTICE which CRAN might complain about or LICENSE which CRAN complains about if it contains permissive licenses for an overall GPL project.

It would also be a good idea to preserve all the original copyright notices in any source files where they are contained. The softwarefreedom.org page has suggestions for that if you are also directly modifying that source file with GPL'ed enhancements but if you aren't changing the included source files you can often leave them untouched.

Comment: Created a new answer since I don't have a high enough reputation score to add comments to Tobu or hadley's answers... In particular the Writing R Extensions file explicitly mentions inst/COPYRIGHTS as an optional file an author can include in their package so is probably preferable to NOTICE which CRAN might complain about and LICENSE which CRAN definitely complains about.

Comment: arent just LGPL-2 ... but LGPL-2?

Comment: People often license code under the LGPL-2 with an (or any higher version) clause meaning the developer can elect to use instead of the LGPL-2 license any higher version numbered LGPL licenses like the LGPL-2.1 license, the LGPL-3 license, etc. including adding a (and any later version) clause.  So if developer elected to use the library under a LGPL-2.1 (or any higher version) license then it would be GPL-3 compatible.  If the original library did not have the (or any higher version) clause to the LGPL-2 license then developer would be forced to use just LGPL-2 which is not GPL-3 compatible.